# Области видимости C#

Tags: c#, ооп

Доброго времени суток!

Возможно ли объявить область видимости метода (класс `А`) таким образом, что его можно вызывать в реализации другого класса (класс `В`), но нельзя вызвать с помощью экземпляра класса `В`? Если да, то как это реализовать?

Пример:

```
class testClassA 
{   
    void test() 
    {
        ...
    }   
}

class testClassB                                                      
{                             
    public testClassA tCa;             
    public void testMethod()  
    {                    
        tCa.test();              
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        testClassB tCb;
        tCb.testMethod(); //корректный вызов
        tCb.tCa.test();   //некорректный вызов
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Поменяйте `public testClassA tCa;` на `private testClassA tCa;`

---

Если вы хотите, чтобы класс `testClassA` вовсе не был доступен, сделайте его внутренним классом класса `testClassB`.

```
using System;

class testClassB                                                      
{                             
    class testClassA 
    {   
        public void test() { /**/ }   
    }

    testClassA tCa;             
    public void testMethod()  
    {                    
        tCa.test();              
    }
}

class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
      testClassB tCb;
      tCb.testMethod(); //корректный вызов
      tCb.tCa.test();   //некорректный вызов
      testClassB.testClassA innerA; // и это тоже не компилируется
   }
}
```

---

Обычно, чтобы сделать класс доступным только определённой группе классов, используется модификатор `internal`. Он делает класс доступным только в своей *сборке*, но не снаружи её. Для этого вам придётся поделить код на сборки, да. (И это решение всё равно не универсально, т. к. вам могут понадобиться разные области видимости для разных классов.)

Трюк с внутренним классом позволяет сделать один или несколько классов видимыми только одному классу.

Answer (score 3):

*Кратко*: нельзя.

*Потому что*: класс `B` видит класс `A` и имеет `public` поле/свойство типа `A` => тогда все, кто видят тип `B`, должны видеть тип `A`.

*Но*: в сигнатуре метода `void testClassB.testMetod()` ничего про класс `A` не сказано, а значит корректность его вызова вообще никак от видимости `A` не зависит. Поэтому в качестве решения вам и предложили скрыть поле/свойство типа `A`.

Еще вариант отвязать полностью `B` от `A`:

```
class testClassB                                                      
{                             
   public Action testAction;
   public testClassB(Action _testAction)
   {
       testAction = _testAction;
   }
   public void testMethod()  
   {                    
      testAction();              
   }
}

// где-то, где виден класс A
var a = new testClassA();
var b = new testClassB(a.test);

//...

// где-то в другой галактике мы можем даже и не видеть класс A, 
// но пользоваться его методом .test() 
b.testMethod();
```

В случае, если класс `B` зависит от нескольких методов класса `A`, то выделяете эти методы в интерфейс и передаете в конструктор `B` экземпляр интерфейса аналогично примеру выше с передачей `Action`.

Но это зависит от того, что от чего вы вообще хотите скрыть :)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к методу test в классе testClassA модификатор protected

Впрочем, нет, присоединяюсь к ответу @VladD

Comment: Разве доступ к protected не осуществляется только из производных родительского класса? В моем случае testClassB не производный от testClassA